Brick work under cement porch

Hi all,
I moved into this house a while back which has a cement porch and bricks all the way under it . They are all just stacked under the entire cement area . The sides seem tightly packed but as you can see the front has spaces between. Ignore that loose brick on the right ..it is just extra.
I am finally getting around to doing something about this and was thinking of just using some mortar around the 2 rows of bricks in the front.
Is this enough or should I be doing anything else? Any tips appreciated since I am a novice.

Can you pull some bricks out and see if there's any kind of support behind them?

Its just stacked bricks that covers the entire cement area - I pulled out a few and checked.

Right, but do you have a photo of what it looks like behind?

Thanks for your replies. I attached a picture after removing the front bricks - it looks like there is sand between the layers so when I removed the front - it sort of pours out and I did not want to go too far in.

It looks like there are more bricks behind?
